# Is there a way to reorder columns in a pandas data frame for hundreds of attributes?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am implementing a classification machine learning algorithm. The dataset contains numerical as well as nominal values in no specific order. The numeric and nominal values are in separate columns but these columns are scattered throughout the dataset. Also, the columns/ attributes are exactly 279 in number. How can I reorder or sort the dataset to have numerical valued columns on one side and nominal valued columns on the other side of the dataset?
P.S. I need to sort the columns so I can implement standardization in this way:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train[:, 49: ] = sc.fit_transform(x_train[:, 49: ])
x_test[:, 49: ] = sc.transform(x_test[:, 49: ])
```

The link to the dataset is provided below for more information.
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Arrhythmia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Select](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) number columns and object (string) columns and then [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them side by side:

```
df1 = pd.concat((df.select_dtypes('number'), df.select_dtypes('object')), axis=1)
```

Comment: The nominal values are also of integer type (0 or 1) not string. So it makes it even difficult to sort.

Comment: Yes, if numeric and nominal values are both numbers you can't sort them by data type, unless all numeric values are floats and all nominal are integers. In this case you could select 'float64'  and 'int64' etc, see linked docs.

Comment: if you know what colums are nominal values you could import them (or convert them later) to strings.

Comment: Yes that I could do but the attributes are 280 in number. So doing it manually is very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can first determine the dtype of the columns with

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

g = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups
```

And then simply get a list of this new order

```
columns_list = []
for key in g.keys():
    columns_list.append(g[key].values.tolist())
columns_list = list(itertools.chain(*columns_list))
```

And finally reindex

```
df = df.reindex(columns_list, axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried this code out but the dataset is altered a lot, to the point where it can't be used to predict. What exactly does this code do? I observed it grouped the columns by integer and float. Which is not what I wanted. The numeric and nominal values are both integers.

Comment: If you know that all your nominal values are 0 / 1 and only them, I would suggest to identify them by

    nominal = []
    numeric = []

    for col in df.columns:
        if df.col.isin([0,1]).all():
            nominal.append(col)
        else:
            numeric.append(col)

    # combine lists either nom or num first
    columns_list = [nominal, numeric]
    columns_list = list(itertools.chain(*columns_list))

    df = df.reindex(columns_list, axis=1)

If not, can you provide a minimal data example here so I do not have to import the whole data from there?

Comment: Thank you for you help! But I used a piece of code that calculated the number of times a value changes in a column. Then whichever column had values changes less or equal to 2 was nominal. It worked fine.

Comment: Well, there are many ways that lead to the desired result. I would be glad if you accept the answer :)

Btw. sorry for the broken format of the previous comment...